# DocumentPicker's DidPickDocument event does not get called on few IOS devices

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms application which uses `UIDocumentMenuViewController` for selecting document.

On iOS version 11.2.2 and 11.1.2 the event "DidPickDocument" does not get called. Whereas, Iphone having version 11.2.1 and 10.3.3 everything works fine.

Below is the code:

```
public async Task<ImportedFile> ImportFile(string descp){
    var ubiq = await Task.Run(() => NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null));
    if (ubiq == null)
    {
        //  throw new Exception("iCloud not available");
    }
    test = new ImportedFile("", null, descp);
    TaskCompletionSource<ImportedFile> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ImportedFile>();

    var allowedUTIs = new string[] {
                UTType.PNG,
                UTType.PDF,
                UTType.Image };

    var activeController = UIControllerHelper.FindActiveViewController();

    //UIDocumentMenuViewController pickerMenu = new UIDocumentMenuViewController(new string[] { "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", "com.microsoft.word.doc", "com.adobe.pdf" }, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
    UIDocumentMenuViewController pickerMenu = new UIDocumentMenuViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
    pickerMenu.WasCancelled += (sender, args) => tcs.SetResult(null);

    pickerMenu.DidPickDocumentPicker += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.DocumentPicker.WasCancelled += (docSender, docArgs) => tcs.SetResult(null);
        args.DocumentPicker.DidPickDocument += (docSender, docArgs) =>
        {
            ImportedFile file = null;

            try{
                var securityEnabled = docArgs.Url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
                var data = NSData.FromUrl(docArgs.Url);
                Helpers.Settings.strImagePath = docArgs.Url.Path;
                file = new ImportedFile(docArgs.Url.LastPathComponent, data.ToArray(), test.Description);
                tcs.SetResult(file);
                //App.GetFile(file);
                GetFileOnDownload(this, file);
            }
            catch (Exception excp){
                tcs.SetException(excp);
            }
            finally{
                docArgs.Url.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
                    //   tcs.SetResult(file);
            }

        };
        activeController.PresentViewController(args.DocumentPicker, true, null);
    };

    pickerMenu.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
    pickerMenu.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        activeController.PresentViewController(pickerMenu, true, null);

    UIPopoverPresentationController presentationPopover = pickerMenu.PopoverPresentationController;
    if (presentationPopover != null){
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        presentationPopover.SourceView = activeController.View;
        presentationPopover.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Down;
        presentationPopover.SourceRect = activeController.View.Frame;
    }
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Please suggest.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UIDocumentMenuViewController class is deprecated in newer ios sdk versions (11.0+). Try to use UIDocumentPickerViewController.
Refer [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Using UIDocumentMenuViewController is also not working in ios 11. Using UIDocumentPickerDelegate instead of the DidPickDocument EventHandler works in ios 11.0+

```
class PickerDelegate : UIDocumentPickerDelegate
{
    public override void DidPickDocument(UIDocumentPickerViewController controller, NSUrl url)
    {
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var pickerMenu = new UIDocumentMenuViewController(s, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
pickerMenu.DidPickDocumentPicker += (sender, args) => {
    args.DocumentPicker.Delegate = new PickerDelegate();
    // Display the document picker
    PresentViewController(args.DocumentPicker, true, null);
};
```